# JavaFX HBox resize policy

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, hbox

Assuming that my HBox has a following children:

```
<HBox fx:id="hBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.controllers.ChatMessageController">
   <children>
      <TextFlow>
      </TextFlow>
      <Label text="|" />
      <TextFlow>
      </TextFlow>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

This HBox can be resized to any values. How can I make sure, that first TextFlow will always fit the size of its content without wrapping?

In other words - I wish the first TextFlow to have an ultimate priority in accesing HBox space.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```xml
<HBox fx:id="hBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="gui.controllers.ChatMessageController">
   <children>
      <TextFlow>
         <HBox.hgrow><Priority fx:value="ALWAYS"/></HBox.hgrow>
      </TextFlow>
      <Label text="|" />
      <TextFlow>
         <HBox.hgrow><Priority fx:value="ALWAYS"/></HBox.hgrow>
      </TextFlow>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Obviously you will need to add the import

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Priority ?>
```

Comment: It should also be possible to specify this as simple attribute without the import `<TextFlow HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>`. Type coercion should take care of selecting the correct enum constant automatically.

Comment: @fabian Thanks: I wasn't sure if that would work or not, and didn't have time to test...